# Global Variable and External functions in SpookyJS

Tags: node.js, global-variables, webautomation, spookyjs

I'm new to SpookyJS/CasperJS and I'm trying to figure out the execution flow.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

- load a page
- store an image of the page
- pass this image to a function and execute it (this process is quite long: ~15 seconds)
- wait for the function to return the result
- use the returned value to fill a field in the form in the loaded page
- submit the form

this is a code snippet which tries to explain the solution I came up with:

```
var globProcessedImage;

try {
    var Spooky = require('spooky');
} catch (e) {
    var Spooky = require('../lib/spooky');
}

var spooky = new Spooky({
    child: {
        transport: 'http'
    },
    casper: {
        logLevel: 'debug',
        verbose: true
    }
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        e = new Error('Failed to initialize SpookyJS');
        e.details = err;
        throw e;
    }

    spooky.start('http://example.com/');

    spooky.then(function() {
        this.captureSelector('./image.png', '#img-node');
    });

    spooky.waitFor(function() {
        this.emit('image.processed');
        return globProcessedImage !== undefined;
    }, function then() {
        processedImage = globProcessedImage;
        this.sendKeys('#imagePassword', processedImage);
    });

    spooky.then(function() {
        this.capture('./page.png');
    });

    spooky.run();

    spooky.on('image.processed', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            globProcessedImage = 'my_result_string';
        }, 15000);
    });
});

spooky.on('error', function (e, stack) {
    console.error(e);

    if (stack) {
        console.log(stack);
    }
});

spooky.on('log', function (log) {
    if (log.space === 'remote') {
        console.log(log.message.replace(/ \- .*/, ''));
    }
});
```

When I run the application I receive the following error:

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: globProcessedImage`

How do I make `globProcessedImage` visible in SpookyJS? Is this the correct approach to deal with external functions during Web automation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is *very* similar to your previous question, ok spookyjs versus casperjs... BTW why is this question tagged casperJS? I will remove it

Comment: Yes, sorry. I needed to understand global variables in CasperJS first and so the differences in SpookyJs. I just wanted to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:* At the time of writing this SpookyJS didn't support the additional syntax of passing objects by value into `waitFor` callbacks. So this code doesn't work.**

In contrast to casperjs, spookyjs has three possible contexts: spooky context, casper context and page context.

What you try is accessing a variable that is defined in the spooky context from the casper context. You can pass variables between the contexts as described in this issue: [How to make global variables available to functions inside casper?](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/issues/27)

So adapting this to your code, you should have:

```
var globProcessedImage;

try {
    var Spooky = require('spooky');
} catch (e) {
    var Spooky = require('../lib/spooky');
}

var spooky = new Spooky({
    child: {
        transport: 'http'
    },
    casper: {
        logLevel: 'debug',
        verbose: true
    }
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        e = new Error('Failed to initialize SpookyJS');
        e.details = err;
        throw e;
    }

    spooky.start('http://example.com/');

    spooky.then(function() {
        this.captureSelector('./image.png', '#img-node');
        // start longRunning here
    });

    spooky.waitFor([{spookyGlobProcessedImage: globProcessedImage}, function() {
        return spookyGlobProcessedImage !== undefined;
    }], [{spookyGlobProcessedImage: globProcessedImage}, function then() {
        this.emit('image.processed', spookyGlobProcessedImage);
        processedImage = spookyGlobProcessedImage;
        this.sendKeys('#imagePassword', processedImage);
    }]);

    spooky.then(function() {
        this.capture('./page.png');
    });

    spooky.run();

    spooky.on('image.processed', function(spookyGlobProcessedImage) {
        this.echo("spookyGlobProcessedImage is " + spookyGlobProcessedImage);
    });
});

spooky.on('error', function (e, stack) {
    console.error(e);

    if (stack) {
        console.log(stack);
    }
});

spooky.on('log', function (log) {
    if (log.space === 'remote') {
        console.log(log.message.replace(/ \- .*/, ''));
    }
});
```

I don't know for sure if `spooky.waitFor` supports this syntax.

Comment: Looks like `spooky.waitFor` is still not able to find `spookyGlobProcessedImage` : `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: spookyGlobProcessedImage`

Comment: @lerio Then I guess waitFor doesn't work like `spooky.then` does. You could open an issue in the github project describing your feature request/bug.